# Nonlinear system with input integral in the state

Tags: control-theory

I have a nonlinear system of the type:

\begin{equation}
\dot{\omega} = A(\omega, u) + B(\omega, u)\cdot \dot{u}
\end{equation}

That is, the state is a function of the integral of the input $\dot{u}$. How can I solve this numerically (e.g. ode45 in Matlab)? Should I create an augmented state of the type:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\omega}\\
\dot{u}
\end{bmatrix}= f(w,u)
\end{equation}
I am a little confused..

Comment: If $u = u(t)$ is given then this equation is just on the standard form $\dot{\omega} = f(\omega, t)$. If $\dot{u}$ is given then you first need to solve for $u(t)$ by integrating up the equation $\dot{u}$.

Comment: ...for this latter case another alternative (insted of solving for $u(t)$ first) is to solve the system $$\left(\matrix{\dot{\omega}\\ \dot{u}}\right) = \pmatrix{A(\omega,u) + B(\omega,u)g(t)\\g(t)}$$
where $g(t) = \dot{u}$ is the given source.